# what was first: view or serializer?

Tags: post, django-rest-framework, django-views, axios, django-serializer

Lately i've face problem of nested objects posting. After researched the proper solution involving either views create() implementation or separate serializers for reading and writing with create() method overriten.

I post with axios, and my object looks like this:

```
{
comment: str
priority: str
file: int // -> this one is ForeignKey for another object and needs its PK which is ID
}
```

The way i want to have my post data structured is:

```
{
comment: str
priority: str
file: str // -> which is file object name
}
```

After sending this request DRF should look in db for file on this name and place its id in this filed.

Is this the proper way ? Or should i nest whole object instead of just its id ?

Another question, offtopic: what is called first after request: serializer or view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) in your serializer

```
file = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='name'
     )
```

But name field of your model should be unique=True

Comment: will this solution allow me for posting data the way i specified in question ? I haven't tested it yet, but wont i get DRF error message like: " file field should contain ID not str" ?
i got this message previously.

Comment: @Wiktoor Yes it will allow you to provide just name of the file, and look for it in db instead of pk lookup, if no file with this name found error will be returned. Please give it a try and get back here :)